# how to make java code to generate access_token & code for the facebook?

Tags: java, facebook

I want to access the data in Facebook but the access token is needed and it changes from time to time, so I need a way to make my application (Java) access this data automatically. Must I have a good way to generate the access token every time the application wants to access data?.

I use the way in this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

So I make the app and get the app id and the secret and it generated this URL:

```
http://www.facebook.com/code=AQATgv4b8yXDeh8Rh9VlJjTUH9z0ux6zfIiw0IzD6Bo1xPWMpbTmNyuz8Hudh7srwYJ3lz6g_oc5vWyPJr8zHtNcqcJLiuzBgcJvF0gzTZoWjS_b4miJjESnduoHxvIBO7eW1Bznl13gC4TLpjECJa2pZ_8V3vOauDC-JlCdK32vGVc_LJNIgDLqil-KUa3Zk8rGAPIvCBjcfxw64mRZEs9z#_=_
```

But the problem is that the code that generated is also changed over the time. I tried to use Java code to get the redirect url but it was not the right way because it return another URL

I search a lot on the internet but I could not find the right way so help me plz.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Spring-social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) and see if that can give you what you need. It's purpose is to integrate with saas services (like facebook).

Answer (score 0):

So in this documentation it said it uses OAuth protocol. You application also should support it. 
I used Spring Security OAuth http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/intro.html library for that: quite easy to configure
It makes all the work for you - generating tokens, redirects and so on.